# Open New Window from Salesforce1 Canvas

Tags: salesforce1-app, canvas

Salesforce1 supports opening of a new window to 3rd party sites by using the `sforce.one.navigateToUrl` command.  Is it possible to do this from within a Canvas app running within Salesforce1?

The developer documents actually recommend using this method:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_apps_salesforce1_navigation_methods.htm

However, the Canvas JavaScript SDK does not include these:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK

How do I get a reference to the `sforce.one` object from within an `<iframe>` that is being hosted on a 3rd party server?